# Failed to parse workflow: json: unknown field "image"

Tags: argo-workflows, argo

apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
generateName: my-workflow-
spec:
entrypoint: my-workflow
templates:

- name: my-workflow-1
  steps:

  - - name: build
      image: docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim-buster
      workingDir: /app
      command: ["sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - |
      yum update && yum install -y git
      git clone https://github.com/my-repo/my-app.git .
      pip install -r requirements.txt
  - - name: run
      image: docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim-buster
      workingDir: /app
      command: ["python", "app.py"]

argo submit -n argo --watch my-test.yaml
result : Failed to parse workflow: json: unknown field "image"

argo lint my-test.yaml
result:
my-test.yaml:
✖ in "my-workflow-" (Workflow): json: unknown field "args"

```
 ✖ 1 linting errors found!
```